# How does MindsDB renew/develop models?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, mindsdb

I've linked a datasource to mindsdb, using scout. I'm wondering, does it automatically pull new data and retrain the model incrementially, or do I have to trigger and retrain the entire thing?

Answer (score 4):

MindsDB supports a [SQL statement](https://docs.mindsdb.com/sql/api/retrain/) that could trigger the retrain of the existing model called `RETRAIN`. For e.g, if your model is called `churn_predictor` you will call:

```sql
RETRAIN churn_predictor
```

Auto-retraining functionality is in beta and it will be first available only for streams(Kafka, Redis).

Answer (score 3):

at the moment in the open-source version you will need to retrain manually. We are looking at releasing model versioning and auto retraining and comparison but this feature is not yet available in the OS version. For more info, you can visit https://docs.mindsdb.com/databases/.

Comment: Can I ask what is your use case and which DB you are using?